# What exactly is the probabilistic/intuitive interpretation of weak mixing of all orders? Why $A_0,\varphi^{\ast n}A_1,\varphi^{\ast 2n}A_2...$?

Tags: definition, dynamical-systems, intuition, ergodic-theory, mixing

$\newcommand{\dlim}{\operatorname{Dlim}}\newcommand{\fix}{\operatorname{fix}}\newcommand{\1}{\mathbf{1}}$I am asking about the interpretations of certain ergodic dynamics definitions, citing [this](https://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/%7Eeisner/book-EFHN.pdf) text from mostly chapter $9$.

First some preliminary definitions for those unfamiliar with the book's notation (the reader can skip most of this section):

> A measure-preserving system is a pair $(X,\Sigma,\mu;\varphi)$, or $(X;\varphi)$ for short, where $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a probability space, and $\varphi:X\to X$ is a measurable map with $\varphi_\ast\mu\equiv\mu$ everywhere. $\Sigma(X)$ denote the "measure algebra" which is the quotient $\Sigma_{/\sim}$ with $A\sim B\iff\mu(A\triangle B)=0$. The "induced map" $\varphi^\ast:\Sigma(X)\to\Sigma(X)$ is defined by $[A]\mapsto[\varphi^{-1}A]$. The *Koopman operator* $T:=T_\varphi$, on any $L^p(X)$, is defined by $T:f\mapsto f\circ\varphi$, which is an isometry satisfying many properties of interest. $\fix(T)$ refers to the eigenspace of eigenvalue $1$: $$\fix(T)=\{f\in L^p(X):Tf=f\}$$
>
> A set $J\subseteq\Bbb N$ is called a subsequence if it has a countably infinite, strictly increasing, enumeration $(j_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ so that $J=\{j_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. The expression $\dlim_nx(n)=y$ means that there exists a subsequence $J$, with asymptotic natural density $\mathrm{d}(J)=1$, for which $\lim_{n\to\infty}x(j_n)=y$ (in whichever relevant topology).
>
> We define a system to be *strongly mixing* if: $$\tag{1}\forall A,B\in\Sigma(X):\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A\cap\varphi^{\ast n}B)=\mu(A)\mu(B)$$
> And *weakly mixing* if: $$\tag{2}\forall A,B\in\Sigma(X):\dlim_n\mu(A\cap\varphi^{\ast n}B)=\mu(A)\mu(B)$$
>
> A function $f\in L^p$ is called *rigid* if there is a subsequence $J$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}T^{j_n}f=f$ in $L^p$. The system is called *mildly mixing* if: $$\tag{3}\forall f\in L^p(X),\,f\text{ rigid}\implies \exists c\in\Bbb C:f=c\cdot\1$$That is, rigidity implies a.e. constancy.
>
> The system is *strongly/weakly* mixing of order $k\in\Bbb N$ if: $$\forall\{A_m\}_{m=0}^{k-1}\subseteq\Sigma(X):\mu\left(\bigcap_{m=0}^{k-1}\varphi^{\ast mn}A_m\right)\to\prod_{m=0}^{k-1}\mu(A_m)$$Where the limit as $n\to\infty$ is taken to be a $\lim$ or a $\dlim$ respectively. The system is strongly/weakly mixing of all orders if this holds for every $k\ge 2$. It turns out that weak mixing implies weak mixing of all orders, but it remains an open problem whether this holds for the strong case.

We have the implications: strong$\implies$mild$\implies$weak (-ly mixing)$\implies$ergodic.

Strong mixing can be nicely intuitively described: if you have some quantity of interest in a set $A$ and you pick any non-null region of space $B$, you can wonder what the relative amount of $A$ in $B$ is after time $n$: $$\frac{\mu(A\cap\varphi^{\ast n}B)}{\mu(B)}$$Now, if the system were thoroughly mixing somehow, you would expect $A$'s contents to be equidistributed over time, so that this relative amount present in any region $B$ converges to the relative amount of $A$ in $X$, i.e. $\frac{\mu(A\cap\varphi^{\ast n}B)}{\mu(B)}\to\mu(A)$ which is $(1)$. Likewise weak mixing just replaces this statement with a weak limit of sorts.

Mild mixing is a head scratch. I know what it means formally, but on an intuitive level the best I can do is (applying to $f$ a characteristic set function): "mild mixing implies that no non-constant set can fully return to itself over any time sequence" - so it must "mix" into other regions of space. The proof that mild mixing implies weak mixing is bizarre and not intuitive (it can be shown that if $T$ has only $\lambda=1$ as an eigenvalue and if $\dim\fix T=1$, then the system weakly mixes) - indeed mild mixing feels like it should be the weakest of them all. **I cannot frame mild mixing in terms of a nice "mixing" property** such as $(1),(2)$, and would appreciate insight from any reader.

Furthermore, the definition for strong/weak mixing of order $k$ is very bizarre. Why do we care about such staggered time intervals as introduced by the term $\varphi^{\ast mn}$? That is, why is the quantity (for e.g. $k=11$): $$\frac{\mu(A_0\cap\varphi^{\ast n}A_1\cap\varphi^{\ast 2n}A_2\cap\cdots\cap\varphi^{\ast 10n}A_{10})}{\mu(A_1)\mu(A_2)\cdots\mu(A_{10})}\to\mu(A_0)$$Of any interest, or meaning? I cannot picture a good "mixing" concept behind knowing that the quantity in $A_0$ is well-distributed over the bizarre time steps of, e.g. $10$ seconds to arrive in $A_1$, $20$ seconds to arrive in $A_2$, ..., $100$ seconds to arrive in $A_{10}$, in the same way that I can for formula $(1)$. Can anyone provide a motivation or an intuition (or even an application!) for this concept?

Many thanks! I am studying raw theory and don't really have a grasp of what all this is *good* for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are good questions.  I can provide a little bit of a historical perspective.  The mild mixing property was introduced by Furstenberg and Weiss in https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0101785.  The motivation was to determine what property of a dynamical system $(X,\mu,T)$ guarantees ergodicity of the product system $(X \times Y, \mu \times \nu, T \times S)$ when we only know that $(Y,\nu, S)$ is ergodic on infinite measure.  In the case of finite measure preserving $S$, it was already known that it is sufficient for $T$ to be weak mixing.  However, if you only know that $S$ is infinite measure preserving, then it is necessary that $T$ be mildly mixing to guarantee that the product system is ergodic.  Also, mild mixing is a nice property for extending much of the theory surrounding rotations, spectrum and disjointness between dynamical systems.  You are correct that mild mixing is just one of many mixing properties: weak mixing, mild mixing, light mixing, partial mixing, strong mixing.  The motivation behind the definition of weak mixing of all orders is combinatorial number theory and Szemeredi's theorem.  Furstenberg used ergodic theory and partly the notion of weak mixing of higher orders to prove Szemeredi's theorem and many generalizations.  Many call it a crown jewel of mathematics.  There have been extensions of weak mixing of higher orders to other sequences such as polynomials.  Here is a popular result in ergodic theory: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/ergodic-theory-and-dynamical-systems/article/weakly-mixing-pet/2E7EE4B1AD5ECBA6F592CFE3476B1CC4.  Above the measure space $(Y,\nu, \mathcal{B})$ is a $\sigma$-finite infinite measure space and $S:Y\to Y$ is an invertible ergodic $\nu$-preserving transformation.  Thus, $\nu(Y)=\infty$ and $\nu(S^{-1}A)=\nu(A)$ for all measurable sets $A\in \mathcal{B}$.  There are many situations where a transformation is nonsingular (preserves sets of measure zero) but the transformation may not be finite measure preserving.  It could be infinite measure preserving.  There has been quite a bit of effort to generalize concepts from probability preserving dynamical systems to dynamical systems on infinite measure spaces.  Mild mixing is a stronger condition such that if $(X,\mu,T)$ is mild mixing and you only know that $(Y,\nu,S)$ is $\sigma$-finite measure preserving (possibly infinite measure preserving) and ergodic, then you know $(X\times Y, \mu\times \nu, T\times S)$ is ergodic.  Mild mixing is the weakest mixing property such that this holds.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this. What do you mean by “ergodic on infinite measure”?

Comment: I edited the bottom of the post to answer your question.  It is interesting to understand the motivation behind many of these notions.  It's not always obvious!